# Kafka java api error?

Tags: apache-kafka

I learn `kafka` by official documents,all command works well.

such as:

step1:start zookeeper

step2:start server

step3:create topic

step4:Send some messages and consume messages.

But i can't use java api to send and consume messages.

[producer api to send 100 messages](http://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html) and [consumer api](http://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html).

Here are the logs when start a producer:

```
[2016-10-24 11:08:28,727] INFO Topic creation {"version":1,"partitions":{"0":[0]}} (kafka.admin.AdminUtils$)
[2016-10-24 11:08:28,737] INFO [KafkaApi-0] Auto creation of topic test2 with 1 partitions and replication factor 1 is successful (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
[2016-10-24 11:08:28,815] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions test2-0 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2016-10-24 11:08:28,825] INFO Completed load of log test2-0 with 1 log segments and log end offset 0 in 3 ms (kafka.log.Log)
[2016-10-24 11:08:28,829] INFO Created log for partition [test2,0] in /tmp/kafka-logs with properties {compression.type -> producer, message.format.version -> 0.10.1-IV2, file.delete.delay.ms -> 60000, max.message.bytes -> 1000012, min.compaction.lag.ms -> 0, message.timestamp.type -> CreateTime, min.insync.replicas -> 1, segment.jitter.ms -> 0, preallocate -> false, min.cleanable.dirty.ratio -> 0.5, index.interval.bytes -> 4096, unclean.leader.election.enable -> true, retention.bytes -> -1, delete.retention.ms -> 86400000, cleanup.policy -> [delete], flush.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.ms -> 604800000, segment.bytes -> 1073741824, retention.ms -> 604800000, message.timestamp.difference.max.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.index.bytes -> 10485760, flush.messages -> 9223372036854775807}. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-10-24 11:08:28,834] INFO Partition [test2,0] on broker 0: No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition [test2,0] (kafka.cluster.Partition)
```

But the kafka file's size is 0Byte.

path:`/tmp/kafka-logs/test2-0/`
files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10485760 Oct 24 11:08 00000000000000000000.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 Oct 24 11:08 00000000000000000000.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10485756 Oct 24 11:08 00000000000000000000.timeindex
```

Comment: How many brokers do you have? What's the partition number for topic 'test2'?

Comment: @amethystic,Only one broker,I don't create topic first,and call producer api to write data directly,defaulte one partition?

Comment: That is confusing: you claim "step3:create topic" and now you say you do not create a topic first? Did you enable automatic topic creating in the brokers (via parameter `auto.create.topics.enable`)?

Comment: Seems you did not produce any message successfully.  What producer did you use? console-producer? If yes, please paste the producer log. What you showed here is from the server side which did not tell us anything wrong

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax,`step 3` create topic `test`(use command),But use ` java  api` to send msg to another topic `test2`.Sorry

Comment: @amethystic,I use 'java api' to produce message,and not successful..There is no other exception log.

Comment: Use console-producer to produce some messages first as the doc says, to rule out any possibility of the server-side error.